# Calculate the angle between a point and a 3D facet

Tags: vector, lua, 3d, angle

I have a 3D point (x,y,z) and a facet which is defined by three (x,y,z) points. I am trying to calculate the angle between the facet and the point. This is so I can shade the facet appropriately as though a light were moving across it in 3D space.

Hopefully this image gives an idea of what I'm trying to work out. The 3 dots are points in space relative to the facet and have different angles relative to its facing direction. It is this angle that I want to find. If the dots were points of light, the black dot would provide the brightest light, the blue would be about 50% brightness and the green would be very dark.
[image]

While I can calculate the magnitude, length and dot product of any two points, I am at a loss as to how to calculate the angle between the facet itself and the point.

I would like to know how to calculate whether the point is above or level with the facet, i.e.: the angle of the point relative to the facet.

The code I have so far is:

```
-- Get length of 2D or 3D vector
local function vector2d3dLength( vector )
    return math.sqrt( vector.x*vector.x + vector.y*vector.y + (vector.z or 0)*(vector.z or 0) )
end

-- Normalise 2D or 3D vector
local function normalise2d3dVector( vector )
    local len = vector2d3dLength( vector )

    if (len == 0) then
        return vector
    end

    local normalised = { x=vector.x/len, y=vector.y/len }

    if (vector.z) then
        normalised.z = vector.z/len
    end

    return normalised
end

local function crossProduct3d( a, b )
    return { x=a.y*b.z − a.z*b.y, y=a.z*b.x − a.x*b.z, z=a.x*b.y − a.y*b.x }
end

local function dotProduct3d( a, b )
    return a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y + a.z*b.z
end

-- subtract vector b from vector a
local function subtract_vectors( a, b )
    local sub = { x=a.x-b.x, y=a.y-b.y }

    if (a.z ~= nil and b.z ~= nil) then
        sub.z = a.z-b.z
    end

    return sub
end
```

Comment: How do you define the angle of a _point_ relative to a face? Do you mean a direction vector?

Comment: By (X,y,z) values. I probably do mean a direction vector but I'm not sure of the difference, I'm afraid.

Comment: Input data is not enough.  You need to provide a point on the facet where you are measuring the brightness. So, program input should consist of: 3 points to specify a facet, 1 point on the facet (the vertex of the angle) and 1 external point (the location of lightsource). @willywonkadailyblah - Probably, OP wants to calculate the angle between facet normal and direction to the lightsource.

Comment: The point on the facet could be the centre. I'm not sure how to calculate that yet, but I expect it is easier than calculating 3D angles. What I'm trying to do is, for example, shade the faces of a cube relative to where a point of light is in the space around the cube. I'm not concerned with distance, only relative angle to each face. (In this case I'm not concerned with edge cases, like the light being inside the cube or in contact with it.)

Comment: You should calculate a normal using `crossProduct3d` of two vectors from the facet; and then find cos(angle) using `dotProduct3d` between normal and vector from facet center to black/blue/green point

Comment: Actually, you don't need an angle, just its cosine.  `Brightness = cos(angle) * max_brightness`

Comment: But that equation includes an angle, which (I think) is the angle that I'm having trouble calculating. No?

Comment: @MattW you can get the cosine _directly_ by the dot product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- black/blue/green point
local lightsource = { x = 111, y = 112, z = 113 }    

-- 3 points on the facet, first point is the center
local facet = {{ x = 1, y = 2, z = 3 },  
               { x = 4, y = 5, z = 6 },
               { x = 7, y = 8, z = 9 }}

local facet_normal = normalise2d3dVector(crossProduct3d(
   subtract_vectors(facet[2], facet[1]),
   subtract_vectors(facet[3], facet[1])))

local direction_to_lightsource = 
   normalise2d3dVector(subtract_vectors(lightsource, facet[1]))

local cos_angle = dotProduct3d( direction_to_lightsource, facet_normal )
-- cos_angle may be negative, it depends on whether facet points are CW or CCW

local facet_brightness = cos_angle * max_brightness
```

Comment: I have added the subtract_vectors() function to my code - is that correct?

Comment: To be able to subtract 2d from 3d vectors: `return { x=a.x-b.x, y=a.y-b.y, z = (a.z or b.z) and (a.z or 0)-(b.z or 0)}`

Comment: Aren't all the vectors involved 3D?

Comment: Thank you for your code. When I run it it only ever returns 0. I don't understand why.

Comment: Not sure what collinear but are the 3 points you provided collinear, because I'm using those.

Comment: Yes, points in my example are collinear (why are you using them instead of your own data?).  You should make a triangle with these 3 points, not a straight line.

Comment: Yes, thanks - I just realised they're a straight line... D'oh! I replaced them with a real facet's vectors and it works just great. Thank you. I'm going to try something to make it apply to a 4 vector facet, because that's my situation, but if I need to I'll just take an average of the two triangular facets.

Comment: For n-vertex facet take a center (arithmetic mean of all vertices) as point1 and two arbitrary vertices as point2 and point3.